# Extracting Express Checkout Tokens

Tags: python, paypal

When it comes to PayPal I'm a total newbie, so, sorry if this is answered somewhere else.  I've checked in multiple locations including here and have been unable to find any information.

I want to integrate paypal with python.

My problem is I'm trying to implement Express Checkout in an e-commerce site.  I'm working on kind of a dummy test site using sandbox to try and get it to work.  As a reference, I've been using https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Chapter 6 as a guide on how to do this.

Where I'm at now is I've gotten everything to work, up until I need to extract the Tokens after a successful invocation to the PayPal API.  Essentially, I get a message in the browser that looks like

```
TIMESTAMP=2007%2d04%2d05T23%3a23%3a07Z
&CORRELATIONID=63cdac0b67b50
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=52%2e000000
&BUILD=1%2e0006
&TOKEN=EC%2d1NK66318YB717835M
```

First, how do I extract the ACK and TOKEN values from the message?  Are these part of hidden query string that I could extract by using something like `Request.QueryString["TOKEN"]`?

Technically, all I need to do is extract and check if ACK is successful, otherwise redirect back with an error.  If sucessful, I need to extract the token and continue on to paypal and eventually redirect to my order review page.

How do I extract the tokens?

How do I redirect the browser from this page?  (I'm working on a local copy that hasn't been uploaded yet.

Sorry for the wall of text.  Please let me know if anyone has any other resources I could review, or if you have any suggestions or solutions for me.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I answered off the top of my head without trying it. Here's what actually works.

```
from cgi import parse_qs
...

redirect_url_template = 'https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey='

...

parsed_response = parse_qs(response.content)
ack = parsed_response['responseEnvelope.ack'][0]
if ack and ack == 'Success':
    url = redirect_url_template + parsed_response['payKey'][0]
```

This is just an example, you'll want to put a try catch around that for KeyError and that sort of thing to be safe.